# How to make smoke flow in different direction?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I am trying to make the smoke flow down from a mesh but at the same time go in the X and Y direction.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

The red lines indicate direction of the smoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the **Temperature Difference** in the Smoke Domain to a negative number.

[image]

Form the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html?highlight=smoke%20domain)

**Temperature Difference**

> The Temperature Difference setting controls how much smoke is affected by temperature.
>
> The effect this setting has on smoke depends on the per flow object
>
> Values above 0 will result in the smoke rising when the flow object Temperature Difference is set to a positive value, and smoke sinking when the flow object Temperature Difference is set to a negative value.
>
> Values below 0 will result in the opposite of positive values, i.e. smoke emitted from flow objects with a positive Temperature Difference will sink, and smoke from flow objects with a negative Temperature Difference will rise.
>
> Note that smoke from multiple flow objects with different temperatures will mix and warm up/cool down until an equilibrium is reached.